# Hooking into the Meta Boxes (Name/Web Address/Description) on the 'Add New Link' Page

Tags: metabox, wp-admin

Is there a way to modify/adjust the meta boxes (Name/Web Address/Description) on the 'Add New Link' page? I'm trying to add some jQuery functionality to them but am unsure how to 'hook' into them.[image]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with those metaboxes, are you perhaps referring to The Title, Permalink, and Content (first 3 main boxes / areas) of the Add New Post screen? Can you upload a screenshot pointing out what you mean maybe?

Comment: These meta boxes are a part of the Links Manager plugin...

Comment: Ok, it's a tad off topic since it's plugin specific but let's just add some more information. Are you trying to add content to the metabox (such as instructions or more information), trying to remove things from the metabox (such as removing the title or deleting the metabox entirely), or are you trying to add jquery validation to the inputs?

Comment: I'm trying to add jQuery validation as well as a button that changes all back slashes to forward slashes and spaces to %20.

Comment: You should use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to add a script to your edit.php footer. You can then use that external script to manipulate the boxes however you'd like. As far as the slashes go, you can use the [`save_post` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and filters the `$_POST` data for the inputs you want to convert spaces and slashes. I'm not familiar with the plugin at hand so I'm not sure of it's specific hooks.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply--it's much appreciated!